# Getting ActionMailer to work with custom SqlTemplate resolver Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a Rails 3 app with a template resolver that pulls templates out of DB as explained in the book Crafting Rails Applications and partly in [this article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/04/default-views-in-rails-3-0-with-custom-resolvers/).

It works fine in controllers, but I'd like it to work in ActionMailer now so that I can also have customizable email templates.

I have the following that works in a `before_filter` in `application_controller.rb`:

```
prepend_view_path SqlTemplate::Resolver.instance
current_theme = @platform.active_theme
SqlTemplate::Resolver.instance.set_theme = current_theme
```

I tried copy/pasting the same in my mailer by only changing the first line to `ActionMailer::Base.prepend_view_path` but it doesn't seem to pick up the new path.

Any ideas?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: sorry, the author and I are working together and I thought it'd be quicker if I just did this...

Comment: ah, ok, sorry then ;) it's not that obvious when just I/others are looking at "user X changed post of user Y" :))